# Apache Jersey exception:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am learning Java rest webservices using Jersey Framework.
 Created one sample project in eclipse but not able to deploy it in tomcat. Below libraries added in eclipse project. Can anyone please help me out here

```
cglib-2.2.jar
hk2-api-2.3.0-b06.jar
hk2-locator-2.1.63.jar
hk2-utils-2.5.0-b04.jar
javassist.jar
javax-inject.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
javax.ws.rs.jar
jersey-bean-validation-2.17.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-guava-2.7.jar
jersey-media-jaxb.jar
jersey-server.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

Getting below error while running project in Apache server inside eclipse.

       SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor.<init>(Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;L
    java/util/Set;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorType;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorVisibility;ILjava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/
    util/Map;)V
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstantActiveDescriptor.<init>(ConstantActiveDescriptor.java:113)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getLocatorDescriptor(Utilities.java:951)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:71)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:270)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5543)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) enter code here
```

Comment: Hello I am not doing any Jasper operations here this plain simple hello world example that I am trying to run in eclipse with above mentioned jars

Comment: This is s a certain kind of `NoSuchMethodError`.  It's not really a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

If you see your exception

```
Apache Jersey exception:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor
```

as per my experience , This Exception `NoSuchMethodError` because of Incompatible jar has been added to your Project `library`.

Use latest jar `hk2-api-2.5.0-b04.jar` instead of `hk2-api-2.3.0-b06.jar` . Probably this will solve your problem..

Comment: I have tried multiple jar version but still same error.